# Why can't I see my accept rate?

Tags: support, faq

As the title says, why can't a user (at least I don't) see his accept rate?

I think that, especially for new members, it would help to remind them to accept answers.

Comment: Perhaps you don't have one: I don't seem to, and I know I've asked 4 questions and accepted all of the answers!

Answer (score 12):

The statistic is only shown if there are at least 4 questions that meet the following criteria:

- Questions must not be community wiki.
- Questions must not be closed.
- Questions must be more than 3 days old.
- Questions must have at least 1 answer.

This feature has also been [blogged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/) about.

Answer (score 2):

You can only see it on your questions, not on your user page.

Rebecca outlined the specifics but I did want to clarify this point.